# Show $u(x)=\tan{(x/\sqrt{2})}$ is a solution to $0= u_{xx} + \frac{1}{2}u(1-u^2)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stationary-point

I come across this problem in my study for diffusion-action nonlinear PDE. I tried to solve the problem explicitly but I stuck as I am going to show. However I solved the solution 2. I am not convinced it even a solution though.

*Solution 1*
$$ u_{xx} = \frac{1}{2}u(u^2-1)$$
multiplying  by $u_x$,

$$2u_{xx} u_x = u^3 u_x-u u_x.$$

Integrating for $x$ from $0$ to $x$ we get

$$(u_x)^2 = \frac{u^4}{4} - \frac{u^2}{2}.$$

Now we solve the ODE,
$$u_x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{u^4}{4} - \frac{u^2}{2}} \Rightarrow u_x = \pm \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{2} - 1}. $$

$$\int \frac{du}{\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{2} - 1}} = \pm \int dx.$$

After I make the substitution $u= \sqrt{2} \sec v$ and calculating the integration on the left as;

$$\int \frac{du}{\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{2} - 1}} = \sqrt{2} \sec^{-1}(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}).$$

Substituting the result in the equation before and simplify I get the general solution

$$u(x)= \sqrt{2} \sec(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+c).$$
boundary conditions. Could you please explain a way to get the right solution mentioned in solution 2. Thanks in advance.
Which does not satisfy the

Solve  $\begin{cases}
 &0= u_{xx} + \frac{1}{2}u(1-u^2),\,\,\, x\in \mathbb{R}\\
 &u(0)=0,\,\, u({\pm \infty})=\pm 1.
 \end{cases}$

*Solution 2*
Consider the  $ u(x) = \tanh{a x}$, where $a >0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align*}
    u_x &= a (1- \tanh^2{(a x)},\\
    u_{xx}&= -2 a^2 \tanh{(ax)} (1 -\tanh^2{(ax)}),\\
    0&=u_{xx}+2a^2 u(x) (1- u(x)^2).\\
\end{align*}

By comparison with the main ODE we get $a = \frac{1}{2}$. Then the solution is $u(x) = \tanh{\frac{x}{2}}$. We can see that  $u(x)$ satisfies the main ODE, and

\begin{align*}
    u(0)&=0.\\
    u(\pm \infty)&=\pm1.
\end{align*}

Comment: If the exercise is to show that $u(x) = \tan(x / \sqrt{2})$ is a solution to the equation, can't you just directly input it and show that the equation is satisfied?

Comment: The exercise is to find the solution of the ODE. But I know the solution from another work.